# Gmail white fonts on white background

Tags: gmail

A friend of mine writes friendly emails to a group (invitations to parties and such) using Microsoft Outlook (desktop client).

For some reason sometimes he uses white fonts on black background, but when I open his messages on Gmail, I get white fonts on white background.

Anyone knows the source of the problem and a possible solution? (Besides telling my friend not to do it again, which I did but he just forgets.)

Comment: How does it work if you highlight the entire email :) Usually that will allow you to read it, though it's very hacky.

Comment: It works! It's what I do when I know what is going on. But sometimes the content has images and colors with white patches and later I find white text on those patches. A bit annoying.

Comment: Yep, it's certainly not the most pretty way to go about this - but at least it allows you to read what's there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Outlook formats HTML messages in a way that Gmail does not completely understand (thus the background missing). Email clients have different support of HTML elements. I know that Gmail supports settings background-image via CSS, but not sure how Outlook sets it. Otherwise the question is too broad to answer without any example emails.

Comment: Good answer so far.  Isn't there a solution yet bisides selecting highlight the entire email?